Setting Livewire V3 property using Alpine $wire | x-on:click="$wire.title = 'title'"
I have been using Livewire v3 for a while and often use...
<button x-on:click="$wire.set('title', 'A New Title')">

... to set Livewire properties directly from Alpine. This all works as intended.
The docs show $wire.title='' as another way of doing this. I like this API, but it does not work for me. Am I misunderstanding the docs?
Ref: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/alpine#mutating-livewire-properties

The syntax $wire.set('property', 'value') triggers a call to the backend and causes a rendering of the view.
Can be equated to wire:model.live="property"
Instead the syntax $wire.variable = 'value' sets the property value locally on the browser side and needs an explicit call to update the backend side (a $refresh can achieve the same result)
Can be equated to wire:model="property"
For example:
<div>
    Counter: {{ $counter }}

    <br>
    <br>

    <button @click="$wire.set('counter', $wire.counter + 1)">
        [ Live + ]
    </button>

    <br>
    <br>

    <button @click="$wire.counter++">
        [ Deferred + ]
    </button>

    <button wire:click="$refresh">
        [ Refresh ]
    </button>

</div>

In the above example the 'Live +' button updates immediately the $counter property on the backend and reflects the change in the view, instead the 'Deferred +' button updates the property locally, so we must use the Refresh button to send its value and receive the updated view
